# It keeps on saying IndexError: String Index out of range

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot and it works fine until I try and use one of the ! commands (Like !hello) and then It comes up with this

```
ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vanti\PycharmProjects\discordbot4thtry\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vanti\PycharmProjects\discordbot4thtry\bot.py", line 33, in on_message
    if user_message[0] == '%':
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The % is supposed to make the bot send you the response in a DM e.g. if I do !hello it would reply in the channel with "Hello there!" but if I put %hello it would send "Hello There!" as a DM

```
import discord
import responses

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'This is where the bots token would go'
    client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

        if user_message[0] == '%':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `on_message` method, are you awaiting `message`?

Comment: @Soumendra `on_message` is called internally by `discord.py`, and `awaiting message` doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `message_content` intent.

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

The class definition will look like

```py
def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'This is where the bots token would go'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: I've added your code to the program and now it has a problem with the token
`code`
File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\discordbot4thtry\bot.py", line 43, in run_discord_bot
    client.run(TOKEN)
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
`code`

Comment: @vantisher It literally tells you what to do & even includes a link... go to your developer portal & enable it. Read the error you get instead of instantly throwing it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the following line to your code :

```
if len(user_message) > 0:
```

Like this:

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

        if len(user_message) > 0:
            if user_message[0] == '%':
                user_message = user_message[1:]
                await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
            else:
                await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You can't physically send empty messages on Discord so this if-statement doesn't do anything - the condition will always be True. He's getting empty messages right now because he doesn't have the intent enabled, so he can't get _any_ messages. If the intent is enabled, an empty message is impossible.